# adding names/values in list

Tags: java, error-handling

I keep getting an IndexOutOfBoundsException when I run the executable. The first name and min_cost print before the error. I know that it is probably trying to access an index that can't be accessed. I can not figure out what is wrong.

```
    for(int j = 0; j <= no_comps-1; j++){ 
                String line2 = in.nextLine();
                Scanner compline = new Scanner(line2);
                int k = j-1;

                String co_name = compline.next();
                int x = compline.nextInt();
                int y = compline.nextInt();
                int val = compute(tot_boxes,my_boxes,x,y);

                List <String> names = new ArrayList <String>(500);
                names.add(j,co_name);

                List <Integer> min_cost = new ArrayList <Integer>(500);
                min_cost.add(j,val);

                    while(j > 1){
                    if(min_cost.get(j) > min_cost.get(k)){
                        Collections.swap(names, j, k);
                        Collections.swap(min_cost, j, k);
                    }
                    else{

                    }

                    }
                System.out.println(names.get(j)+ " " +min_cost.get(j));
```

Thanks in advance for any help!

Edit:

```
DHL 46
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 1, Size: 0
at java.util.ArrayList.rangeCheckForAdd(ArrayList.java:612)
at java.util.ArrayList.add(ArrayList.java:426)
```

Comment: Please, edit your post with the [stack trace](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stack_trace)

Answer (score 1):

**Edit:** Now that you have posted the stack trace, please check `if (min_cost.size()==0)` as you are trying to access the second element `1` when the list size is `0`.

I would suggest you to declare `Lists` outside `for loop`:

```
List <String> names = new ArrayList <String>(500);
List <Integer> min_cost = new ArrayList <Integer>(500);

for (...) {

// Your code

}
```

and use the list variables inside to access values.

What is happening right now is that you are creating new `Lists` every time the loop is executed. The problem starts when the value of `j=2`. You again create new `Lists` and assign values.

But then for `j=2` your `if (j>1)` becomes true and you try to compare

```
if(min_cost.get(j) > min_cost.get(k))
```

You have initialized `k` as:

```
int k = j-1;
```

so for `j=2`:

```
k=1
```

And `min_cost.get(k)` -> `min_cost.get(1)`

But since you created new `Lists` inside `for loop` that value doesn't exist.

Hence, it throws `IndexOutOfBoundsException`.

Comment: +1: And the reason that the first `name` and `min_cost` are printed is that for `j == 0`, all uses of `k` are not executed because they lie within the loop starting `while(j > 1){`.

Answer (score 0):

Why are you recreating the names and min_cost objects within the loop? Whatever you add to the ArrayList will be gone each iteration of the loop. I'm guessing the Exception occurs when you try to call `min_cost.get(k)`. Try putting these lines above the for-loop:

```
List <String> names = new ArrayList <String>(500);
List <Integer> min_cost = new ArrayList <Integer>(500);
```